# How to disable cookies without same site must be secure in chrome driver 85?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to disable in earlier version of chrome driver.but not able to disable in chrome driver 85.

Comment: how do you try to disable cookies?

Comment: I have used this code.but can not disable in latest version of chrome
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeLocalStatePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> experimentalFlags = new ArrayList<String>();
experimentalFlags.add("same-site-by-default-cookies@2");
experimentalFlags.add("cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2");
chromeLocalStatePrefs.put("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", experimentalFlags);
options.setExperimentalOption("localState", chromeLocalStatePrefs);

Comment: Any sollution for it?

Comment: ChromeOptions     options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--disable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure");                                                                                      also tried this one.